# how to set launch condition order in visual studio 2008?

Tags: c#, windows-installer, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have an WPF and SQL-Server Express based app which I want to deploy using VS-2008 setup and deployment project template. I have added Launch condition for Windows Installer 3.1, Sql Express 2005 and .Net FrameWork 3.5 with SP1 but they are not running in order. I mean:

1. Windows Installer checking
2. .Net Framework 3.5 sp1 checking
3. SQL-Server Express 2005 checking

When i built my project and ran on test machine (with Fresh XP installation only) it tried to install SQL-Server Express 2005 first and then failed for windows installer 3.1.

One more thing i want to know how i can run my DB script after installation of SQL-Server Express 2005.

How I can solve these 2 issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your question actually deals with LaunchConditions as the purpose of LaunchConditions is to prevent the installation of a Windows Installer package if certain conditions aren't met.   What you are describing sounds morel ike prereq chaining although I'm not certain what tool you are using to author your install and thus which setup.exe to do the chaining.

I'd also look at putting MSI 4.5 in your chainer, MSI 3.1 is very old in the tooth and only applies to Windows XP these days as all newer OS's come with atleast 4.0.

Comment: It was my mistake, actually I was executing .msi package instead setup.exe
thanks Chris